# How to truncate clob conversion in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, listagg

Assume we have a query like

```
select LISTAGG(message, '. ') as joined_message
from messages
group by session_id
```

If we run this query, we will recieve

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

It's understandable, we can just add "on overflow truncate"

```
select LISTAGG(message, '. ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) as joined_message
from messages
group by session_id
```

But then we receive something like

```
DatabaseError: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: XXXX, maximum: 4000)
```

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, but you one method that comes close is:

```
select listagg(case when running_len < 2000 then message end, '. ') within group (order by message) as joined_message
from (select m.*,
             sum(len(message) + 2) over (partition by session_id order by message) as running_len
      from messages m
     ) m
group by session_id;
```

Note:  This truncates by message, so it does not include a partial message at the end.  Also, it orders arbitrarily by the message.  You might have some other way of ordering them.

Comment: Let's assume N rows, where 1st row is 1999 chars in length. As far as i understand `listagg(case when running_len < 2000 then message end, '. ') `  will try to produce first message + N dots between 'nothing'. It is not what we expect, isn't it?

Comment: @Gleb . . . As I say, this is a simple method that comes close.  You can adjust the arithmetic if this is a concern (subtract "2" in the subquery).  You can also order by message length so the smaller messages come first.